# jQuery .change selected value preselected

Tags: jquery, selected

I want to update a cookie (via update.php) and reload the site by transferring the new data (id, value). Value 1 is preselected and using jQuery sets str = 1, not the selected option value e.g. 6.

```
    $( ".a2d" ).change(function() {
       var prodId = this.id;
       var e = document.getElementById(prodId);
       var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
       var url = "../update.php?id=" + prodId + "&updateNewValue=" + str;
       $(location).attr('href',url);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<select class="a2d" id="2" name="2">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

By using

```
var str = $('#' + prodId).options[this.selectedIndex].val();
```

It seems to work better (as it gets the correct selected value), but an error in firebug says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#' + prodId)
```

This is a jquery object, not javascript object hence use it like :

```
document.getElementById(prodId).options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the selected index, just get the value of the `<select>`

```
var str = $('#' + prodId).val();
```

But since `prodId` is `this.id`, you can just use:

```
var str = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the value of the select element by using the `this` reference

```
$(".a2d").change(function () {
    var str = $(this).val();//or just this.value
    var url = "../update.php?id=" + prodId + "&updateNewValue=" + str;
    $(location).attr('href', url);
});
```

In your case `$('#' + prodId)` returns a jQuery object which does not have the `options` property that belongs to the dom element reference.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value, just try,

```
var str = $('#' + prodId).val();
```

or

```
var str = this.value;// best option
```